# How to read from an Excel file?

Tags: x++, axapta

I have to read from a Excel file using X++ Code. Bellow is the some content as part of a large excel file. I would only need to filter list *_BillingCode, *_PSN, AccDistRuleAdvLedgerEntryExt etc on the basis of Public Sector in first column cells.

```
Public Sector SL1   *_BillingCode
Public Sector SL1   *_PSN
Public Sector SL1   AccDistRuleAdvLedgerEntryExt (Class)
Public Sector SL1   AccJourRuleAdvLedgerEntryExt 
Public Sector SL1   AccountantActivities
Public Sector SL1   AccountingManagerActivities
Public Sector SL1   AdvancedLedgerEntry (Class)
Public Sector SL1   AdvLedgerEntry (Prefix)
Public Sector SL1   AxAdvancedLedgerEntry (Prefix)
Public Sector SL1   AxdAdvancedLedgerEntry
Public Sector SL1   AxdCustomerTransaction (Class)
Public Sector SL1   BudgetAccountDetail (Prefix)
```

I searched on google I found following lines of code to read from excel file.

```
    static void ReadFromExcel(Args _args)
    {
    SysExcelApplication application;
    SysExcelWorkbooks workbooks;
    SysExcelWorkbook workbook;
    SysExcelWorksheets worksheets;
    SysExcelWorksheet worksheet; 
    SysExcelCells cells;
    COMVariantType type;
    int row;
    CustAccount account;
    CustName name;
    #define.Filename('C:\\X++ Ownership.xls')
    ;
    application = SysExcelApplication::construct();
    workbooks = application.workbooks();
    try
    {
    workbooks.open(#Filename);
    }
    catch (Exception::Error)
    {
    throw error("File cannot be opened.");
    }
    workbook = workbooks.item(1);
    worksheets = workbook.worksheets();
    worksheet = worksheets.itemFromNum(1);
    cells = worksheet.cells();
    do
    {
    row++;
    account = cells.item(row, 1).value().bStr();
    name = cells.item(row, 2).value().bStr();
    info(strfmt('%1 - %2', account, name));
    type = cells.item(row+1, 1).value().variantType();
    }
    while (type != COMVariantType::VT_EMPTY);
    application.quit();
    }
```

It is taking time to understand how could I utilize the above code, in order to meet my requirements. I would be thankful for your help.

Comment: Can you save the file as a .CSV, if so I can help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are better ways to read Excel files, see [Axaptapedia](http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php?title=ExcelIo) (I am the author by the way).